# How to keep scroll position after selecting an item react native flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

Found answer -- had to do with having styled components around certain items

Whenever I have a long list and I scroll down to select an item, after selection, it'll jump back up to the top. How can I make it so after selection, the screen does not change?

When trying to look more into this, I get search results for this problem but when adding new items or how to implement infinite scroll which is not the situation here.

I've tried assigning a ref to the flatlist and after the action trigger by selecting an item, scroll to the last saved position, but that doesn't change anything.

```
<FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 10}}
                data={stores as Stores[]}
                renderItem={({item}): JSX.Element => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={(): void => setState(item)}>
                        <Text>{item}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={(): JSX.Element => <ItemSeparator />}
                keyExtractor={(item): string => item.id.toString()}
                ListHeaderComponent={
                    <ListHeader />
                }
            />
```

Comment: A click should not change the scroll position of a flat list. Is your application's behaviour different to this: https://snack.expo.io/@vijaydemonz/flatlist-example?

Comment: yes, it's a different behavior, perhaps because i'm using setState in the button's action

Comment: Could you re-create this by editing the snack example?

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the fact that I had a custom component that was saved in another file where I passed this value as a child. It ended up re-rendering and refreshing the page!